# Parsing multiple JSON files and writing to text

Tags: php, json

Is there a way to optimize this to run faster?

The script reads multiple JSON files based on station codes and then writes only the variables I want.

```
        <?php
        $wuStations = array(
            'KORHALFW4','KORHALFW3','KORHALFW5','KOROXBOW2','KIDCOUNC2','KIDNEWME2','KIDNEWME4',
          'KIDMIDVA5','KIDCAMBR6','KIDCAMBR4','KORRICHL2','KIDWEISE16','KORONTAR3','KIDWEISE5',
          'KIDPAYET7','KORONTAR6','KORONTAR4','KIDSWEET2','KIDLOWMA5','KIDIDAHO11','KIDLOWMA2',
          'KIDHORSE8','KIDEMMET9','KIDGARDE6','KIDBOISE233','KIDBOISE208','KIDBOISE262',
          'KIDPARMA7','KIDPARMA8','KIDWILDE7','KIDHOMED2','KIDHOMED4','KIDCALDW11','KIDKUNA8',
          'KIDMERID68','KIDBOISE104','KIDBOISE90','KIDBOISE270','KIDBOISE121',
          'KIDBOISE138','KIDBOISE93','KIDBOISE158','KIDBOISE223','KIDBOISE207','KIDBOISE230',
          'KIDBOISE231','KIDBOISE68','KIDSTAR3','KIDSTAR5','KIDEAGLE20','KIDBOISE148',
          'KIDEAGLE20','KIDEAGLE28','KIDMIDDL6','KIDMOUNT9','KIDMERID54','KIDMERID35',
          'KNVJARBI2','KIDOLA2','KIDOLA6','KIDBOISE226','KIDKINGH2','KIDFAIRF4','KIDFAIRF7',
          'KIDWESTM2','KIDGOODI9','KIDGLENN4','KIDGLENN5','KIDBLISS3','KIDBLISS2','KIDHAGER3',
          'KIDBUHL7','KIDBUHL10','KIDFILER7','KIDTWINF306','KIDTWINF293','KIDKIMBE4',
          'KIDALBIO3','KIDMURTA3','KIDOAKLE5','KIDBRUNE3','KIDHAMME3','KIDHAMME2','KIDMURPH4',
          'KIDMELBA2','KIDMELBA3','KOROREGO24','KORCRANE2','KORBURNS11','KORWESTF6','KORBAKER15',
          'KORVALE6','KORNYSSA2','KIDPARMA7','KIDPARMA8','KIDWILDE7','KIDHOMED2','KIDHOMED4',
          'KIDCALDW11','KIDKUNA6','KIDBOISE80','KIDBOISE133','KIDEAGLE20','KIDBOISE148',
          'KIDEAGLE20','KIDEAGLE28','KIDMIDDL6','KIDMOUNT9','KIDMERID54','KIDMERID35',
          'KNVJARBI2','KIDOLA2','KIDOLA6','KORSUMPT2','KORBAKER12','KIDINDIA3','KIDINDIA2',
          'KIDDONNE6','KIDDONNE5','KIDIDAHO30',
            );
        $start = microtime(true);
        foreach ($wuStations as $sta) {
          //JSON
          $wu_url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/606f3f6977348613/conditions/lang:EN/q/pws:'.$sta.'.json';
          //READ JSON
          $wu_data = file_get_contents($wu_url);
          $wu = json_decode($wu_data, true);
          $loc = $wu['current_observation']['display_location']['full'];
          $lat = $wu['current_observation']['observation_location']['latitude'];
          $lon = $wu['current_observation']['observation_location']['longitude'];
          $elev = $wu['current_observation']['observation_location']['elevation'];
          $id = $wu['current_observation']['station_id'];
          $ob = $wu['current_observation']['observation_time_rfc822'];
          $tf = $wu['current_observation']['temp_f'];
          $tdf = $wu['current_observation']['dewpoint_f'];
          $wdir = $wu['current_observation']['wind_degrees'];
          $wspd = $wu['current_observation']['wind_mph'];
          $wgst = $wu['current_observation']['wind_gust_mph'];
          $pcp = $wu['current_observation']['precip_1hr_in'];
          echo $id.','.$lat.','.$lon.','.$elev.','.$ob.','.$tf.','.$tdf.','.$wdir.','.$wspd.','.$wgst.','.$pcp;
          echo PHP_EOL;
        }
        $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
        echo "Elapsed: $elapsed seconds\r\n";
        ?>
```

Comment: Hi korri, welcome to Stack Overflow, this question probably fits the Code Review site better https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests.

The two longest tasks (no surprises here), were the **fetching of URLs**, and **decoding of JSON**.

To optimise it further, you'd probably need to share some usage patterns with us.

But briefly, URLs could be fetched concurrently or even as a batch job somewhere else.

For JSON decoding, well, that's a bit more tricky. I notice that the JSON returned is formatted quite nicely (visually). Perhaps instead of decoding the JSON, you could jump to the line number and read the value directly (haven't tested timing for this yet).

Or, again depending on usage patterns, if the batch job could re-format the data and store it somewhere for retrieval later, there could be some time savings.